# External tensor product Calabi-Yau DG categories

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, rt.representation-theory, ct.category-theory, derived-categories

Let $\mathcal{C}$ be a smooth proper DG-category such that the shift $[p]$ is a Serre functor for $D^{perf}(\mathcal{C})$ (we say that $D^{perf}(\mathcal{C})$ is $p$-Calabi-Yau). I am looking for a reference for the following lemma:

**Lemma** : The shift $[2p]$ is a Serre functor for $D^{perf}(\mathcal{C}^{op} \otimes \mathcal{C})$.

Thanks a lot for your help!